# IOS status bar setTranslucent(true) React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying without success to change the background color of the ios status bar or to set it NON-transparent in react native.

```
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(LightTheme.primary);
StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);

<SafeAreaProvider>
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: LightTheme.primary }}>
    <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} />
    ....
  </SafeAreaView>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

The thing is working fine in Android, but the status bar remains transparent in IOS.

I need it to be NON-transparent cause I'm sliding a view up, but the problem is that this view stays in front of the status bar. Also in IOS, I'm getting this error: setTranslucent is only available in Android. Is there any workaround?

Here an illustration of the behavior. As you see the 2 buttons in the right "Add" and "Search" are in the front of the statusbar

[image]

Comment: Could you please add screenshots or video?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak just did.

Comment: you need to add SafeAreaView for the screen with  "Add" and "Search" buttons